# Return only Id of child entity with symfony serializer

Tags: symfony, doctrine, serialization

I am using symfony/serializer in my project and would like to return the only id of a child entity. e.g. I have these two entities of Order and User.
When I fetch the orders and return the result I only want the Id of the user. I have managed to do this by using @Groups but it feels a lot of work to add a group to every single property in the class in case I have another request which needs all the details.

```
/**
 * Order
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="orders")
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class Order
{
    /**
     * @var int
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="Id", type="integer", nullable=false)
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var Users
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Users")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="UID", referencedColumnName="UID", nullable=false)
     */
    private $user;

    /**
     * @return int
     */
    public function getId(): int
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * @return Users
     */
    public function getUser(): Users
    {
        return $this->user;
    }

    /**
     * @param Users $user
     * @return Order
     */
    public function setUser(Users $user): Order
    {
        $this->user = $user;
        return $this;
    }

}


/**
 * Users
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="users")
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class Users
{
    /**
     * @var int
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="UID", type="integer", nullable=false)
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
     */
    private $UID;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="FirstName", type="encrypted", length=255, nullable=false)
     */
    private $FirstName;

    public function getUID(): ?int
    {
        return $this->UID;
    }

    public function getFirstName(): ?string
    {
        return $this->FirstName;
    }

    public function setFirstName(string $FirstName): self
    {
        $this->FirstName = $FirstName;

        return $this;
    }

}
```

Comment: If you are using JMSSerializerBundle you could check virtual properties

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have created a custom normalizer that does this. Not sure if this is the perfect solution but works for me. I found writing groups for all the entities too much of a hassle.

```
use Doctrine\Common\Annotations\AnnotationException;
use Doctrine\Common\Annotations\AnnotationReader;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\Entity;
use Symfony\Component\Serializer\Normalizer\NormalizerInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Serializer\Normalizer\ObjectNormalizer;

class EntityNormalizer implements NormalizerInterface
{
    const ID_ONLY_ATTRIBUTES = 'ignored_attributes';

    private $normalizer;

    /**
     * IdOnlyNormalizer constructor.
     * @param ObjectNormalizer $normalizer
     */
    public function __construct(ObjectNormalizer $normalizer)
    {
        $this->normalizer = $normalizer;
    }

    public function normalize($object, $format = null, array $context = [])
    {
        if (
            $context[self::ID_ONLY_ATTRIBUTES]
            && (in_array(get_class($object), $context[self::ID_ONLY_ATTRIBUTES]))
        ) {
            $data = $object->getId();
        } else {
            $data = $this->normalizer->normalize($object, $format, $context);
        }

        return $data;
    }

    public function supportsNormalization($data, $format = null)
    {
        $supports = false;
        if (!is_array($data)) {
            try {
                $reflectionClass = new \ReflectionClass($data);
                $reader = new AnnotationReader();
                $annotation = $reader->getClassAnnotation($reflectionClass, Entity::class);
                $supports = !is_null($annotation);
            } catch (AnnotationException $e) {

            } catch (\ReflectionException $e) {

            }
        }
        return $supports;
    }
}
```

Comment: this is a really dirty solution, check this documentation for ignore attributes in normalizer/serializer https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/serializer.html#ignoring-attributes

Answer (score 1):

You can serialize all the entity without specify any group

```
$serializer->serialize($order, 'json');
```

In case that you want to serialize a child, you have to do what you are saying. Set groups in every property what you want to return.

```
$serializer->serialize(
    $order,
    'json', ['groups' => 'order-user']
);
```